# How to change the login screen background from terminal?

Tags: live-cd

I am in the process of customizing a live cd. I have changed the default ubuntu wallpaper in live cd, however the same got reflected in login screen. I just want to change the wallpaper alone and not the login screen background. Any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the login screen in Ubuntu 10.10

- Open a terminal and to activate the Appearance window upon login enter the command

`sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow`

- Close the terminal. Log out of your current session. At the login screen, the Appearance window will show up.
- Make changes and login. To deactivate the Appearance window upon login enter the following command in a terminal.

`sudo unlink /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/
gnome-appearance-properties.desktop`